# Finding duplicates in Array of structure

Tags: qt

I am using QT to search for duplicate entries in a structure.I have a struct as follows:

```
struct information{
QString fname;
QString lname;
QString gender;
QString age;
QString cod;
```

};

I have this code here which has bool variable for each variable in the structure and changes the bool value to true if data in the two arrays are the same and checks to see if all the bool values are true and prints out the two lines where duplicates are.

```
for (int i=0; i<numlines; i+=1){
    for (int j=i+1; j<numlines; i+=1){
        bool fname = false;
        bool lname = false;
        bool age   = false;
        bool cod   = false;
        bool gender= false;

        if (person[i].fname == person[j].fname){
            fname = true;
            //qDebug() <<fname;
        }
        if (person[i].lname == person[j].lname){
            lname = true;
            //qDebug() <<lname;
        }
        if (person[i].gender == person[j].gender){
            gender = true;
            //qDebug() <<gender;
        }
        if (person[i].age == person[j].age){
            age = true;
            //qDebug() <<age;
        }
        if (person[i].cod == person[j].cod){
            cod = true;
            //qDebug() <<cod;
        }
        if (fname==true && lname==true && gender==true && age==true && cod==true){
            //print out where duplicate are.
            //duplicates at line i+1 and j+1

        }
    }
}
```

When I click my duplicate check button which activates the code it enters the loop once and terminates the program unexpectedly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0; i<numlines; i+=1){
    for (int j=i+1; j<numlines; i+=1){
        //                      ^
```

Simple problem (probably cut'n'paste error) - you need to increment `j`, not `i`.

---

And, as an aside, you could probably refactor your code to make it a bit simpler since, if any field *doesn't* match, you can just move to the next, something like (pseudo-code):

```
for i = 0 to (sz - 2) inclusive:
    for j = (i + 1) to (sz - 1) inclusive:
        if person[i].fname  != person[j].fname:  continue
        if person[i].lname  != person[j].lname:  continue
        if person[i].age    != person[j].age:    continue
        if person[i].cod    != person[j].cod:    continue
        if person[i].gender != person[j].gender: continue

        // they're all equal at this point, log the fact.
```

This removes the need for those boolean variables.

---

But, if you *do* decide to keep the booleans, you can make your code more readable by choosing their names carefully. I tend to prefer booleans to be readable such as `customerIsDead` or `managerHasPsychopathicTendencies`. That way, they "flow" easier when reading the code:

```
if (sameFName && sameLame && sameGender && sameAge && sameCod) {
```

You should generally *never* have compare a boolean value with true or false since that just gives you another boolean and, as per reductio ad absurdum, where do you stop?

```
if ((((x == true) == true) != false) == true) ...
```

Comment: Could you explain to me how the inclusive works? I've never really seen this type of format for coding before. And what would sz be in this case? Would that be the number of things in the array ?